# Question about how to study for engineering university exams

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, control-engineering

What are some of the ways to predict exam questions from class lectures in university final exams? How should one understand the mindset of the professor & find out important maths/questions he may give in the exam?

Comment: One of the dangers of trying to predict what questions might be asked on exams is you study those topics & not others. This can leave you with a knowledge deficit as an engineering, which is a bad thing. In studying engineering you need to acquire a certain level of knowledge & understanding, not study for a particular exam. If you're not prepared to study **all** that is required & face an exam on any aspect of the course you will not be a good engineer. Do you want to be an engineer or do you only want to acquire a status symbol?

Comment: Why don‘t you just study, become informed of the subject and then just write the exam confident you know the subject and be prepared for anything…and not try to learn tricks to pass?

Answer (score 2):

Try to find the exam questions for the past few years (At least two). The source where you find them is a good indicator if you can predict the questions.  Usually if you find them

- from other students or online forums curated by students, chances are that you have some prediction. (some lecturers can limited -- for whatever reason-- in their choice of questions, and in that case they don't want to advertise that -- I've seen that too often).
- from an online forum (eclass) curated by the lecturer, chances are that it will be very difficult to predict the next questions.

In any case, if you really want to study (not cheat), you can use those questions as practice. My advice is read the question and try to solve the problem without checking the solution. At the end check the provided solution (if there is one). If you get stuck and you can't solve it, then read the solution, and then try to solve the problem again without help a few hours or a day or two later.

Using this method, chances are that you will familiarise yourself  with the key concepts of the module, therefore you'll end up being better prepared for any "new" exam questions.

Answer (score 2):

#### Do the assigned homework problems.

These will be similar to the exam questions.  Other than that, memorize the things you have to memorize.

Comment: Anything else I have to do besides homework problems & past papers?

Answer (score 1):

Check past questions if they are available.

Do NOT try to predict the next ones, but consider the level of questions asked.